# snapcraft export-login and login command error

Tags: login, snap

I am trying to use the snapcraft export-login and login command, but I am encountering an error. After exporting my snapcraft credentials using the following command:

snapcraft export-login snaplogin

I try to login with the following command:

snapcraft login --with snaplogin

But I receive the following error message:

Cannot parse config: File contains no section headers.

I have tried checking the format of the file and the contents, but the issue still persists. I would greatly appreciate any help or advice on how to resolve this error.

Thank you in advance for your time and support.
snapcraft version: snapcraft 7.2.9
snapcraft log:

```
2023-02-11 23:53:15.585 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-02-11 23:53:15.585   File "/snap/snapcraft/8619/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snapcraft/store/_legacy_account.py", line 53, in _load_potentially_base64_config
2023-02-11 23:53:15.585     parser.read_string(decoded_config_content)
2023-02-11 23:53:15.585   File "/snap/snapcraft/8619/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 723, in read_string
2023-02-11 23:53:15.585     self.read_file(sfile, source)
2023-02-11 23:53:15.585   File "/snap/snapcraft/8619/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 718, in read_file
2023-02-11 23:53:15.585     self._read(f, source)
2023-02-11 23:53:15.585   File "/snap/snapcraft/8619/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 1082, in _read
2023-02-11 23:53:15.585     raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
2023-02-11 23:53:15.585 configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
```

Comment: Not seeing anything in your question that relates to this site. Are you sure this is the place for this question?

Comment: Yup. my question is related to snapcraft and snap, which are part of the Ubuntu app store.

Comment: But not part of the Ubuntu OS which is all the volunteers here can deal with.  Stackexchange main site may be a better choice or someone there can point you to the best site.

Comment: @David snap questions are on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also have seen this in the output:

*--with is no longer supported, export the auth to the environment variable 'SNAPCRAFT_STORE_CREDENTIALS' instead*

Indeed, the [documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapcraft-authentication) says:

"*Warning: The login --with argument is not supported in Snapcraft 7 and is currently included to help users migrate from the old authentication method to the new.*"

So I'd recommend using the other method detailed on that page.

```bash
export SNAPCRAFT_STORE_CREDENTIALS=$(cat snaplogin)
snapcraft whoami
```

Should return your logon details, for example:

```bash
email: [redacted]
username: popey
id: [redacted]
permissions: package_access, package_manage, package_metrics, package_push, package_register, package_release, package_update
channels: no restrictions
expires: 2024-02-15T10:11:42.000Z
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much.